# boolean returns same answer despite value change

Tags: java

Im trying to find true or false values based on the number of likes and retweets it gives me, by the second  kindaLiked method it should return true but it returns false. first one works fine along with the notLiked method.
output im looking for
true
false
true
false
false
false
true
msg aplus rt 75 lk 51
output im getting
true
false
false
false
true
false
false
msg null

```
Tweet sample = new Tweet("aplus", 0, 0 );
        sample.addLikes( 3 );
        sample.addRetweets( 28 );
        System.out.println( sample.notLiked() );
        System.out.println( sample.kindaLiked() );
        sample.addLikes(35);
        System.out.println( sample.kindaLiked() );
        System.out.println( sample.isTrending() );
        sample.addLikes( 13 );
        sample.addRetweets( 47 );
        System.out.println( sample.notLiked() );
        System.out.println( sample.kindaLiked() );
        System.out.println( sample.isTrending() );
        System.out.println( sample );
```

```
public boolean notLiked()
    {
        if (likes < 10)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean kindaLiked()
    {
        if (likes < retweets)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isTrending()
    {
        if ( retweets + likes >= 75)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "msg " + message;
    }
}
```

after the value of retweets and likes changes Im still getting the same true/false value

The code is presented to us as fill in the blank so im trying to avoid adding more methods

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java

Comment: What `addLikes` does?

Comment: Note `if (something) { return true; } return false;` can be shortened to `return something;`. You should also show your example output, in addition to the methods you've used in your example (e.g. `addLikes`, `addRetweets`, etc)

Comment: kindaLiked is true if likes < retweets; You start with 3 < 28 -- true; then you have 38 < 28 -- false. Why do you think that 38 < 28 should return true?

Answer (score 0):

your desired output is:

```
true false true false false false true
```

lets take the first scenario

```
        sample.addLikes( 3 );
        sample.addRetweets( 28 );
        System.out.println( sample.notLiked() );
        System.out.println( sample.kindaLiked() );
```

we can easily see that in the start you have

```
3likes, 28retweets.
```

and lets take `kindaLikes()` method:

```
    public boolean kindaLiked()
    {
        if (likes < retweets)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

is `if likes < retweets return true` and `3<28` so it will return true.

so it looks like you did `true true...` you should change the `<` to `>` that makes the `likes` greater than `retweets`.